# twitter4j Streaming tweets

Tags: java, twitter4j

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException{
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());
}
public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
public void onException(Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using the above code to download streaming tweets.
 I get this error .

`The type new StatusListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method StatusListener.onStallWarning(StallWarning)

The type new StatusListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method StatusListener.onScrubGeo(long, long).`

Do I need to include any specific jar file?

Comment: no, you need to implement those methods

Comment: No. You need to do what the error says - it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: As per API, http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusListener.html, StatusListener is an interface, and yes, you must implement the all of the interface methods.

Comment: i implemented the StatusListener.onStallWarning(StallWarning), StatusListener.onStallWarning(StallWarning).  Now I am getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.conf.Configuration.isStallWarningsEnabled()Z
 at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:60)
 at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40)
 at twitterstream.Twiterstream.main(Twiterstream.java:21)

Answer (score 1):

No need to include any more .jar files, only include the method below

```
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
        }
```

Your code will compile and run successfully.

Hope this helps!!!